Automatically deploy from GitHub to cPanel
I want to set up automatic deployment from GitHub to cPanel whenever I push code to GitHub from VS Code, but it is not working.
I have successfully set up manual deployment from GitHub. However, I want to set up deploy head commit deployment. For this, I tried using the following configuration:
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/MY_CPANEL_USERNAME/public_html/
    - /bin/cp * $DEPLOYPATH


but deploy head commit not enable in cpanel
